# Error during cmake build : CXX compiler must support Cilk

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, cilk-plus, cilk

I am trying to install cilk++ according to [this website](http://cilk.mit.edu/download/#mac-os-x-installation) and am at the steps in section "Cilk Plus Runtime". When I go to build, I get the following output:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:132 (message):
  CXX compiler must support Cilk.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/cilkrts-0.1.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/cilkrts-0.1.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I thought clang and clang++ (which I checked with --version are indeed installed) would be sufficient. Do I need to update clang and clang++? There are no troubleshooting steps on the instructions website, so I'm not sure what I need to do to finally get cilk++ up and running on my laptop.

Thanks in advance,

Anthony

Comment: The Cilk GitHub page specifies that your compiler must be a **Cilk-enabled branch** of Clang (see [here](https://github.com/OpenCilk/cilkrts#1-building)). Is this what you are using?

Comment: @squareskittles Honestly, I wasn't, but in the process of installing a new compiler I ran into a [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192073/error-during-cmake-build-missing-header-file-that-i-know-the-path-to-mac)

Answer (score 0):

*Expanding on my comment:*

When you configure this Cilk Plus Runtime with CMake, CMake first verifies the compiler by attempting to compile a simple test program (see [here](https://github.com/OpenCilk/cilkrts/blob/507a93234a480431ee8f7e49bbb464e3572618f5/CMakeLists.txt#L114)). If the compilation fails, CMake prints the error you see:

> ```
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:132 (message):
>   CXX compiler must support Cilk.
> ```

On the Intel Cilk Plus runtime Github page ([cilkrts](https://github.com/OpenCilk/cilkrts#1-building)), it has some compiler requirements listed for those trying to build this library:

> You need the CMake tool and a C/C++ compiler that supports the Cilk language extensions. The requirements for each operating systems are:
>
> - Common: CMake 3.4.3 or later Make tools such as make
> - Linux: Tapir/LLVM compiler, or GCC* 4.9.2 or later (depracated), or Cilk-enabled branch of Clang*/LLVM* (http://cilkplus.github.io), or Intel(R) C++ Compiler v12.1 or later (depracated)
> - OS X: Tapir/LLVM compiler, or Cilk-enabled branch of Clang*/LLVM* (http://cilkplus.github.io), or Intel C++ Compiler v12.1 or later (depracated)

Since you are using Clang as your compiler, be sure it is a **Cilk-enabled branch** of Clang, as specified in the requirements. Or, you can try to use the Tapir/LLVM compiler.